# findOne with Mongoose/MongoDB not returning row

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following setup.

The me = is incoming data from the request but since it's not used in this example I am skipping the info.

Added the findAndUpdate I am trying to do. Why is there an insert being done on findAndUpdate instead of an update?

app.js

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/time_report");

var reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    month: String,
    date: String,
    hours: Number,
    dayNumber: Number,
    day: String
});
var time = mongoose.model("time", reportSchema);
```

Query:

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
var me = new time({
            name: info[i + 3],
            month: info[i + 1],
            date: info[i + 2],
            hours: info[i],
            dayNumber: info[i + 4],
            day: info[i + 5]
        });

    time.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("data: " + data);

        found = true;
    });
```

}

..... More stuff and listener

In MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598d71b20f47692f48eb7393"), "name" : "jocke", "month" : "2017-08", "date" : "2017-08-01", "hours" : 8, "dayNumber" : 2, "day" : "Tuesday", "__v" : 0 }
```

Mongoose debug:

```
[0;36mMongoose: times.findAndModify({ date: '2017-08-31' }, [], { '$set': { hours: null } }, { new: false, upsert: false, fields: {} })
[0;36mMongoose: times.insert({ name: '', month: '2017-08', date: '2017-08-31', hours: null, dayNumber: 4, day: 'Thursday', _id: ObjectId("598d7ef69386343b3035192f"), __v: 0 })
```

Comment: *"The console.log will never execute in this scenario."* which means the `if (err) ` is returning true. So what is the error?

Comment: why are you creating instance using new for finding the element

Comment: There is no error it will just skip ahead since it's nog getting a hit. The new instance is for time when you don't find something. Then it will be saved as a new object

Comment: What does "skip ahead" mean? The method is either called or it is not. It either returns an error or it does not. And when it does not, then the next line of code executes. Do you actually connect to the database anywhere? turn on debugging `mongoose.set('debug', true)`

Comment: Yes it's connecting and several other queries return data. That's what's thowing me off here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mongoose model exported just use below code

```
var time = require('./models/time');

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  // change the search object as per your need like month=2018/07
  time.findOne(req.body, function(err, doc){
   if(err) return handleError(err);
   res.send(doc)
  })

})
```